# What does Java static object mean?

Tags: java, object, static

What is the advantage if we make object as static? Seeking detailed explanation !!

Comment: Do you mean a static variable that references an object?

Comment: You cannot make an object static. That's basically the point of static. `static` means the item resides the "class world", not the "object world". So `static` says: "one meta-level higher".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Classes can have fields, and they are not always primitive types.

Comment: So, is this invalid ?     public static ResultSet resultSet;

Comment: @Gendarme That's true, but where did Willem say that this wasn't the case?

Comment: @Gendarme: yes, but I don't see why that is relevant?? "The flag of Texas consists out of red, blue and white". This is also an irrelevant fact.

Comment: For this example `static ResultSet resultset` reference refer to same object in which class's static variable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem @byxor If the field isn't a primitive type, then it is an object, no? For example `class Foo { static ArrayList<Integer> = new ArrayList<Integer>(); ... }`. You have created an object with the keyword `new`, have you not?

Comment: Yes and the **field** is static, not the **object** itself... That is also mentioned in the question: "static variable".

Comment: @mustafacil But what can be an advantage of making it static ? can you think of an example

Comment: @DeepakGarg Give an example of a *"static variable"* and a *"static object"*, and we can help you from there. Right now we do not know what you mean, since you are using the terminology wrongly.

Comment: if i have a connection class in which i have resultset as a static object, so does it mean that every time i create a new connection objetset object, I will be accessing the same resultset object. But if this is so, I am wondering, what would be benefit of such a scenario? Because i would need a new resultset object with every new connection.

Comment: @DeepakGarg It would be beneficial when you actually **want** to be accessing the same `ResultSet` each time. You do not seem to want to do that, so don't make the field static.

Comment: @Gendarme forget about static variables. I have edited the question. I just need to know about JAVA STATIC OBJECT.

Comment: For example, I'm writing a program about my properties including my cars, my flats, my clothes, my shoes. Can you realize this? If car, flat, clothes, shoe are a class, the common field in this all classes is me. And I must be a static fiels. Otherwise un-solicited status can occur.

Comment: @DeepakGarg Give a code example of what you mean. Your question is still not clear. There is, as explained above, nothing called a *"static object"*.

Comment: I think i got the answer. One usecase is that they are used in Singleton pattern. @Gendarme : static objects do exist. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make a Variable static, and this Var is refering to an Object, Why would it be good? well a static means that it will be visible to all aplication (well also depends of its package visibility, public, protected, default, private)

Why would be good? well maybe you're creating an "static object" in order to use it in diferent objects for example a game, look i made one ("of course it is an example")

```
public class Dummy {
    static Player player = new Player("Yussef");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stageOne();
        satageTwo();
    }
    static void stageOne(){
        System.out.println("Ready? Go");
        System.out.println(player);
        System.out.println("Ouch an enemy hit me");
        player.setLife(80);
        System.out.println(player);
    }

    static void satageTwo(){
        System.out.println("Good, now you're in next level");
        System.out.println(player);
        System.out.println("Ouch an enemy hit me");
        System.out.println("Ouch an enemy hit me");
        player.setLife(40);
        System.out.println(player);


    }


}

class Player{

    private String name;
    private int life;

    Player(String name){
        this.name = name;
        life = 100;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "My name is: "+name+" And mi actual life is: "+life;
    }


    public void setLife(int life) {
        this.life = life;
    }
}
```

Now Imagine inspite of using the same class, i would've made more Clases, or more players, well the poit is this: My player will have the same life in all my game, and same name, so no matter what stage i play i will have the same attributs or changed them maybe ;).

It is an example i thought, hope it could help u